# Error al cargar Floating Actions Menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola el error es que sigo los pasos para agregar un Floating Actions Menu pero cuando lo voy a cargar en el activity me sale los siguientes errores

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FloatingActionButton_fab_colorNormal
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.init(FloatingActionButton.java:76)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton.init(AddFloatingActionButton.java:36)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:66)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton.<init>(AddFloatingActionButton.java:23)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton.<init>(AddFloatingActionButton.java:19)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu$1.<init>(FloatingActionsMenu.java:148)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.createAddButton(FloatingActionsMenu.java:148)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.init(FloatingActionsMenu.java:109)
    at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.<init>(FloatingActionsMenu.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:220)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

y cuando reviso no tengo error en los pasos a seguir .

Este es el codigo xmnl:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabledimension"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu


            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >





        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FloatingActionButton_fab_colorNormal

estas tratando de cargar un estilo el cual no existe en el Android SDK

```
R.styleable.FloatingActionButton_fab_colorNormal
```

realizando una búsqueda encontré que hay proyectos que usan este estilo como:
https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

o como:

https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button 
que es el que al parecer tratas de usar pero de hecho son proeyctos obsoletos (DEPRECATED).

**lo recomendable es usar [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) el cual requiere API 22.2.0 o mayor.**